# React inline style with const and "text"

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to have a const style and inline hardcoded style to my element lets say I have this:

```
const style = {
    cursor: "pointer",
    border: "2px solid #b1b1b1",
    borderRadius: "8px",
    padding: "0px 10px 0px 10px",
    backgroundColor: "green"
}
```

But I also want additional style to the element lets say width

```
<div style={style{width: "20%"}}>test</div>
```

This is not working, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax for assigning your styles.

```
<div style={{...style, ...{width: "20%"}}}>test</div>
```

```js
const style = {
    cursor: "pointer",
    border: "2px solid #b1b1b1",
    borderRadius: "8px",
    padding: "0px 10px 0px 10px",
    backgroundColor: "green"
}

const newStyles = {...style, ...{width: "20%"}};

console.log(newStyles);
```